# Dreamweaver: Display folder name in title bar or tabs

Tags: dreamweaver

I work on a number of sites that compartmentalise controllers into folders - 
e.g.: news/index.php, news/view.php, pages/index.php, pages/view.php, etc.

I'm finding it very difficult to use Dreamweaver to edit these sites as the tabs and title bar only shows the name of the document and I get lots of "index.php", "index.php", "index.php" documents that are impossible to differential from one another unless I actually load them and look at them.

Is there a solution to display the parent folder somewhere, e.g.: "pages/index.php" instead of just "index.php"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so. you better name your files with different names. than with a different directory. it's just my advice. good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think so. I'll just stick to my current practice of closing tabs as often as possible to save confusion.